# Make a div hide with left to right hide animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions

Hi guys I have a situation where I have to hide a div from left to right with a hide animation.

Here is a demo

[image]

When I click on the full screen toggle button, I want the code editor to take full screen.
Currently I am doing this:

```
(e) => {
  $(e.target).children('i').toggleClass('rotate180');
  $('.editor-container').toggleClass('full-width');
  $('.input-output-container').toggleClass('hide');
 }
```

Here are the definition for '.editor-container', '.input-output-container', '.full-width' and '.hide'

```
  .editor-container {
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;

  &.full-width {
    width: 100%;
  }
 }

.input-output-container {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 8.4vh);
  background-color: gt.theme-var(ide-bg-1, null, $thememaplight, $cssvars);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;

  &.hide {
    animation: slide_right 0.5s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
 }
   
@keyframes slide_right {
   0%{
     width: 50%;
    }
    
 100%{
  width: 0%;
  padding: 0;
 }
}
```

There is a weird collapse of the `.input-output-container` because I am setting the `padding` and `width` to  `0`.

We can see a flash of the scrollbar towards the end and the placeholders getting squished.
I want to make the slide out animation as smooth, good looking as the slide in animation.

Is there any other way I can achieve this animation without setting the width, padding to 0.

Any help is appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into transform: translateX(...)?

Comment: yes @AHaworth, it just moves my div to the right but the code editor cannot take the full width

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit of the requirement. So what if you try moving the item left: 100% in the animation?